# In my garage can a refrigerator and a separate deep freezer be plugged into the same outlet

Tags: electrical

Electrical
Can a refrigerator and a deep freezer in a garage be plugged into the same outlet

Comment: Do you know how many amps/watts they draw?

Comment: Is the GFCI something you put in voluntarily, or was it forced upon you because of a house sale or inspection?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to find out how many amps that circuit provides and, if possible, how many amps or watts each unit can pull. In terms of watts, a 15 amp circuit gives 1800 watts, and 20 amps is 2400 watts. If your fridge and freezer aren't crazy old, there should be a label inside the door that tells you this. My freezer says it's 5 amps and my younger fridge says 3 amps (for comparison). Older devices may vary, depending on the size.

To find out how many amps that plug can give, plug something like a lamp in and flip breakers until it goes out. That breaker will tell you how many amps it is.

Comment: One more thing to add: Once you figure out which breaker it is, see what *other* receptacles, lights, etc. are connected to that same breaker. A few lights (fluorescent or LED) are no big deal. But if the receptacle you use for your table saw or other heavy equipment is on the same breaker then you may want to think twice.

Answer (score 0):

You may be fine,if new, And they could start at the same time and trip breaker.  Would run on separate or even better own circuit. There are other post about this question may want to look up. Seeing that they are both old and on a gfci , Would not do it.may trip gfci .And you say other loads on circuit.Trouble.

Comment: Thank you they are old they are both plugged into old outlet in garage how many amps on outlet and circut can anything else run on that circuit  the gfic is old

Comment: I put a latch on my dishwasher door it works but now it won't finish a cycle it keeps running

Comment: You really do not want them plugged into a gfci. Old equipment and old gfcl. Could trip an spoil food.